# Is there a standard set of reports that can be applied to any dataset?

Tags: prediction, reporting, business-intelligence

I work for a small recycling firm and we have built and maintain a stock management system. I've been asked to implement some reports over our dataset but I have no background in BI or statistics. I'm wondering if there are a well known set of basic reports and analyses that can be applied to any dataset to start to glean useful BI/MI from it?

The dataset is comprised of deliveries coming into the business and orders going out of the business. Customers will generally order the same few products repeatedly but there is no hard limit on this. Deliveries coming in to the business are not predictable i.e. we don't order our stock, it is sent to us when secondary customers have finished with it (we're  recycling firm), but we generally have sufficient stock to fulfil all outgoing orders.

Comment: There is no such thing as standard reports. Reports are driven by business needs. Of course there are things that are common to many organizations such as sales trends, profitability, inventory, etc. I recommend you look at "Datawarehouse Toolkit" by Kimball. It is a data design book, but will give you a good starting point for various business cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Cagdas. I think it would be useful to have as a full-blown answer.